# Can't remove document file from Media

Tags: webforms, media

I've created a WebForm that allows a user to upload a document file.  The file stores to Media which I'm using for images.  I can delete the image files but I'll be dog-gone if I can figure out how to delete the document files.  I've deleted the WebForm submission but when deleting the file in Media, I get the 'in use and cannot be deleted' message. Does anyone know how to delete this type of file?  I'm in the Administrator account so privileges shouldn't be the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to delete or remove the file from any nodes, or webform submissions that it references. There should be a usage tab on the actual media resource. I don't have a media site handy so I can't provide screenshots. Once that usage tab is empty, it **should** be possible to delete that file. Otherwise I'd check the recent log messages in `admin/reports` to see if there's a file permissions issue, like the only file owners can delete files.